# Get Unique Value from Each Date

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula

1. There is a table of data that consist of date and city.
2. The city may appear more than once in a date.
3. I want to make a new table with FILTER or UNIQUE or some other formulas that can get a new table that consists of date and unique city (without duplicates)
4. The example can be seen in this link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15-PauS118Nm9CWNaIEwwsOvyX0jWVzfeZHIJMmZ_j9k/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need is:

```
=UNIQUE(A3:B)
```

[image: 0]